# Visualforce actionFunction not working when used with jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery, actionfunction

I'm developing a visualforce page and using jQuery in it to identify if the user has scrolled through a div to its bottom (scrolling down is assumed as a confirmation that the user has read all the contents with in that div). There is a checkbox below this div, which is disabled until the user scrolls down the div. However, the checkbox is remaining disabled even after I scroll down to the bottom of the div. Can anybody please help me here? Thanks in advance!

**Following is the jQuery code I'm using:**

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('#agreement').scroll(function() {       
    if ($j(this).scrollTop() + $j(this).innerHeight()>=$j(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        callEnableCheckbox();
    }
});
</script>
```

**This is the div:**

```
<div id="agreement" style="overflow:auto; text-align:left; height:500px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; padding:5px;">
<!-- Some Text -->
</div>
```

**This is the actionFunction that activates the following checkbox:**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callEnableCheckbox" action="{!enableCheckbox}" oncomplete="return false;" rerender="hiddenField,confirm"/>
<apex:inputHidden value="{!disabled}" id="hiddenField"/>    
<apex:inputCheckbox id="confirm" disabled="{!disabled}" value="{!accepted}" required="true"/>
```

**Controller methods:**

```
public <constructor>(){
    disabled = true;
}

public PageReference enableCheckbox(){
    disabled = false;
    return null;
}
```

**Note:** It worked fine when I used the following javascript method and "onscroll" (in the div) along with the above actionFunction and controller methods:

```
function callApexOnScroll()
{
    callEnableCheckbox();
}

<div id="agreement" onscroll = "callApexOnScroll(); return false ;" style="overflow:auto; text-align:left; height:500px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; padding:5px;">
<!-- Some Text -->
</div>
```

But the problem with the above solution is that the checkbox is enabled even before the scroll bar reaches the bottom of the div. It is enabled right after the scrolling has started which is not an ideal solution as it has to be enabled only after the user has scrolled down the div completely.

Comment: You might have already done this, but to troubleshoot the problem further, try adding a console.log('I should enable here'); right before you call your action function. Additionally, add console.log('function complete'); as the first part of your oncomplete. This will give you a little insight into where the breakdown is occurring.

Comment: Why are you returning false oncomplete?

Comment: I'm using it to avoid the full page refresh after the jQuery calls the callEnableCheckbox method.

Comment: Did you try those console.log statements? If so, which printed?

Comment: @D.S. When I checked the console log, it shows the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. (anonymous function) @ vfPageName:5

Here are the lines 5,6, & 7in the vf page: 
   
    if ($j(this).scrollTop() + $j(this).innerHeight()>=$j(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        callEnableCheckbox();
    }

Comment: How are you loading jQuery? It sounds like the library is not loading properly if it is cominaing about jQuery being undefined. This will prevent any of your code from running properly.

Comment: I changed the <script> tag to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> and then it stopped throwing that error. But still, nothing is logged in the console when I scroll down and the checkbox is remaining disabled.

Comment: I have changed my javascript method to: 

function callApexOnScroll()
{
 var scroll = document.getElementById("agreement");
 if(scroll.scrollHeight - scroll.scrollTop == scroll.clientHeight)
  callEnableCheckbox();
}

Comment: This javascript solution is working fine with onscroll = "callApexOnScroll(); return false ;" (enabling the checkbox only when the scrollbar reaches the bottom). I'm proceeding with this solution in my visualforce page instead of using jQuery, but if anyone can find a solution for the issue with the jQuery code I posted,  it would be helpful for others who face a similar issue in future. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. In one function name, you've got an uppercase `C` and in another you've got a lowercase `c`. The `name` attribute on the `<apex:actionFunction` tag is used as the name of the JavaScript function when it is rendered into the page.

Because you have `<apex:actionFunction name="callEnableCheckbox"` you must call this function with a lowercase `c`.

```
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j('#agreement').scroll(function() {       
        if ($j(this).scrollTop() + $j(this).innerHeight()>=$j(this)[0].scrollHeight){

            // lowercase c to match the name on the actionFunction tag
            callEnableCheckbox();
        }
        else {}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have corrected it to lowercase (callEnableCheckbox) and it is still not working.